# htaccess extract path only from THE_REQUEST into a variable

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables

This should be rather simple, but after trying for several hours and also searching everywhere, all the related answers do not suffice.

I have this so far:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([a-zA-Z0-9-_/\.]+)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=TRGT:%1]
```

What the match ***should*** be doing is the following:

1. for URL `example.com` it should contain nothing, or not be defined
2. for URL `example.com/` it should contain nothing, or not be defined
3. for URL `example.com/some-word` it should contain `some-word`
4. for URL `example.com/some-word/` it should contain `some-word`
5. for URL `example.com/some-word/?foo=bar` it should contain `some-word`
6. for URL `example.com/another_word/` it should contain `another_word`
7. for URL `example.com/folder/file.ext` it should contain `folder/file.ext`
8. for URL `example.com/some/other.dot?bar=foo` it should contain `some/other.dot`
9. for URL `example.com/thing.ext/?foo=bar&bar=foo` it should contain `thing.ext`

What I have so far seems to be working, except for when the request ends in `some/` -or `some/?thing=wat` .. then it contains `some/`

I think I'm missing something really simple; any help will be appreciated, thank you.

### UPDATE

I've managed to achieve these exact requirements with the following code, but, after trying many ways to do it in a 1-liner it fails horribly, so I did it in several lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\s)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HREFPATH} (^.*)?\?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HREFPATH} /(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HREFPATH} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
```

If anybody can reduce that to a s3xy 1(or 2)-liner I will choose your answer; thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm missing what tells it to "trim slashes"

Comment: Why are you doing this by checking THE_REQUEST in the first place? Apparently all you want is the path component of the URL, with an optional trailing slash _not_ matched - so that should be achievable using a RewriteRule alone. `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ - [E=TRGT:$1]`

Comment: @CBroe - the reason why I'm using `THE_REQUEST` is because for some genius reason, the `$1` value in this case is not constant, the same as `REQUEST_URI` .. it changes according to the endpoint; e.g: if you either `redirect` or `rewrite` the request to some other place -even before the logic reaches that point, the value of `REQUEST_URI` (or `$1`) has already changed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869599/htaccess-how-to-apply-regex-patterns-on-the-output-of-another-encapsulation/63870016#63870016) the following fulfills the requirements of the question:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*?)/*[\s?]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
```