# htaccess - how to apply RegEx patterns on the output of another - encapsulation

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm performing several regular expressions on a string inside a variable in order to clean it up for further use in the htaccess rules, but it seems rather cumbersome to do such simple thing in several lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\s)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HREFPATH} (^.*)?\?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HREFPATH} /(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HREFPATH} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
```

How can I reduce this to 2 lines?

Basically I'm looking for a way to encapsulate each as aggregation steps (filter) based on the output of the previous expression, but my humble efforts have failed after trying and web-searching for hours.

The code above does what I need it to do, it's just really ugly (not elegant).
In PHP, or basically any decent(ish) language it could be as simple as:

```
$HREFPATH = trim(explode(explode(" ",$THE_REQUEST)[1],"?")[0],"/");
```

-but this is NOT a PHP-related question; merely a simple way to explain what I mean, and what I'm trying to achieve.

I know there may be many RegEx patterns that could (theoretically) work here, but it should be compatible with Apache's RegEx engine.

Any input will be rewarded in kind; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing in multiple rules can be done in a single like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*?)/*[\s?]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HREFPATH:%1]
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s`: Match a whitespace
- `/+`: Match 1+ `/`s
- `([^?]*?)`: Lazily match 0 or more of any characters that are not `?`. Capture this value in `%1`
- `/*`: Match 0 or more trailing `/`s
- `[\s?]`: Must be followed by a `?` or a whitespace